# How to force jscodeshift/recast to keep trailing commas in object expressions?

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I've been writing some transforms to help me refactor the code base. What I'm doing is basically adding a new property to some object expressions. Why does `jscodeshift/recast` remove trailing commas from those objects? How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recast has a [trailing comma option](https://github.com/benjamn/recast/blob/ee038411e51deaa1e95f2440d17f1cd9ed0cf197/lib/options.js#L63-L66):

```
// If you want to print trailing commas in object literals,
// array expressions, functions calls and function definitions pass true
// for this option.
trailingComma: false,
```

You can pass recast printing options to jscodeshift's to `toSource` method [as explained here](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift#passing-options-to-recast):

```
return x.toSource({trailingComma: true});
```

Now that the issue in comments below has been merged, you can also use it this way for more granularity:

```
trailingComma: {
    objects: true,
    arrays: true,
    functions: false,
}
```

---

> Why does jscodeshift/recast remove trailing commas from those objects?

Recast cannot remove something that doesn't exist. Recast operates on the *AST* of the code. Punctuators such as the comma to separate properties doesn't exist in the AST.

Comment: Hmmm that works for me because our style guide recommends trailing commas everywhere. But what if I need to keep the original existence or lack of trailing comma for each object?

Comment: Ugh, this option enables trailing commas in function calls too :(
There doesn't seem to be an option for disabling function call trailing commas, is there?

Comment: Not atm. But you can raise on issue or make a PR to the recast repository to add that :)

Comment: For people who are interested, here is the issue I opened: https://github.com/benjamn/recast/issues/335